# get both unique count and max in group-by of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Using Pandas data frame group by feature and I want to group by column `c_b` and (1) calculate unique count for column `c_a` and column `c_c`, (2) and get the max value of column c_d. Wondering if there is any solution to write one line of group by code to achieve both goals? I tried the following line of code, but it seems not correct.

```
sampleGroup = sample.groupby('c_b')(['c_a', 'c_d'].agg(pd.Series.nunique), ['c_d'].agg(pd.Series.max))
```

My expected results are,

**Expected results**,

```
c_b,c_a_unique_count,c_c_unique_count,c_d_max
python,2,2,1.0
c++,2,2,0.0
```

Thanks.

**Input file**,

```
c_a,c_b,c_c,c_d
hello,python,numpy,0.0
hi,python,pandas,1.0
ho,c++,vector,0.0
ho,c++,std,0.0
go,c++,std,0.0
```

**Source code**,

```
sample = pd.read_csv('123.csv', header=None, skiprows=1,
    dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:float})
sample.columns = pd.Index(data=['c_a', 'c_b', 'c_c', 'c_d'])
sample['c_d'] = sample['c_d'].astype('int64')
sampleGroup = sample.groupby('c_b')(['c_a', 'c_d'].agg(pd.Series.nunique), ['c_d'].agg(pd.Series.max))
results.to_csv(sampleGroup, index= False)
```

Comment: .@lin ma SO is not a personal tutorial service!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a dict to `agg()`:

```
df.groupby('c_b').agg({'c_a':'nunique', 'c_c':'nunique', 'c_d':'max'})
```

If you don't want `c_b` as index, you can pass `as_index=False` to `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('c_b', as_index=False).agg({'c_a':'nunique', 'c_c':'nunique', 'c_d':'max'})
```

Comment: Thanks HYRY, I do not know we can even do in this way after reading a few related questions! Cool! One more issues after trying your code, I tried to print `sampleGroup.columns` after group-by and assignment `sampleGroup = sample.groupby('c_b').agg({'c_a': 'nunique', 'c_c': 'nunique', 'c_d': 'max'})`, I find there are only 3 columns in `sampleGroup.columns`, which are `Index([u'c_a', u'c_c', u'c_d'], dtype='object')`, wondering how to make the group key `c_b` as one of the column in group-by results?

Comment: Thanks HYRY, it works for me. Mark your reply as answer. :)